# Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setCustomPrice() on boolean magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart, shopping-cart, quoteitem

> Here i am trying to add product to the cart using customerId and
>   productId without customer logged in, it's working fine but its not
>   adding custom Price to that product,please guide me if you have any
>   idea related it.
>
> Error "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   setCustomPrice() on boolean" because function $this->getProductQuote($product); returning false.

```
 <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

    use Vendor\Module\Api\CustomerServiceInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollection;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory as ProductFactory;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface as StoreManager;

    class Customerservice implements CustomerServiceInterface
    {

        private $productCollection;

        private $ProductFactory;

        protected $_storeManager;

        protected $_product;

        protected $_customerserviceFactory;


        protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

        protected $_quoteModel;


        protected $_productRepository;

        protected $_cartManagementInterface;

        protected $_cartRepositoryInterface;

        protected $_cart;

        protected $_customer;
        protected $checkoutSession;
        protected $customerSession;

        protected $formKey;   

        public function __construct(ProductCollection $productCollection,
        ProductFactory $ProductFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\CustomerserviceFactory $customerserviceFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quoteModel,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
        StoreManager $_storeManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey)
        {

            $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
            $this->ProductFactory = $ProductFactory;
            $this->_storeManager = $_storeManager;
            $this->_customerserviceFactory = $customerserviceFactory;
            $this->_product = $product;
            $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
            $this->_quoteModel                   = $quoteModel;
            $this->_productRepository            = $productRepository;
            $this->_cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
            $this->_cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
            $this->_cart = $cart;
            $this->_customer = $customer;
            $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
            $this->customerSession = $customerSession;

            $this->formKey = $formKey;
        }

        public function customerservice($params) {

            $customerId = 13;
            $productId = 82;   
            $customprice = 160;
            try {

                    $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    "product" => $productId,
                    "qty" => 1,
                    "price" => $customprice
                    ); 

                    $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                    $request->setData($params); 
                    $customerData = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
                    $quote_data    = $this->_quoteModel->loadByCustomer($customerData);

                    if (!$quote_data->getId()) {
                        $quote_data->setCustomer($customerData); //error line here
                        //$quote_data->setIsActive(1);
                        $quote_data->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                    }
                    $quote_data->setCustomer($customerData);
                    //$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
                    $product = $this->ProductFactory->create()->load($productId);
                    $quote_data->addProduct($product, $request);
                    $customerEmail = $customerData->getEmail();

                    $this->_customer->setWebsiteId(1); 
                    $customer = $this->_customer->loadByEmail($customerEmail); 
                    $this->customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

                    $product = $this->ProductFactory->create()->load($productId);

                    if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                        $item = $this->getProductQuote($product);
                        $item->setCustomPrice($customPrice); // setting custom price
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
                        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                        $this->_cart->save();
                    }
                        $quote_data->collectTotals()->save(); 
                    if($this->customerSession->getId()) {
                        $this->customerSession->logout();

                    }  
                    $quote_data->collectTotals()->save(); 
                    echo json_encode("product added");
                    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                print_r($ex->getMessage()); exit;
            }

        }

        public function getProductQuote($product) {
            $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();        
            $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);        
            return $cartItems;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to check if the `addProduct()` is adding the product to cart.

You can also try the following way

```
$quoteItem = $quote_data->addProduct($product, $request);
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
```

Comment: this code is executing now but not adding custom price to product

Comment: yes addProduct() is adding the product to cart

Comment: I want to add product with custom price, but the above code is only add the product but the custom price is not set to that product

Comment: Check if customer session $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn() is returning true and you are saving cart after modified price.

Comment: buy in my scenario without login using customer id i want to add product with custom price

Comment: I understand that ... But to debug check if its returning true. Also since you have you set customer id you will not be needing that code.